# Merging multidimensional arrays with matching values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a `$list` array that looks like this if `print_r($list);`

```
Array
(
    [0] => images/announcement
    [1] => images/background
    [2] => images/background/thumbnail
    [3] => images/character
    [4] => images/character/frame
    [5] => images/character/party
    [6] => images/particle
    [7] => images/story/background
    [8] => images/story/character/1016/face
    [9] => images/unit/thumbnail
    [10] => images/user_title/background
    [11] => ss/chapter_background
    [12] => ss/others/ability_board_s
    [13] => ss/others/common/back-light-2
    [14] => ss/others/common/back_light_s
```

This is the resulting array structure (in JSON) I am wanting to achieve (Note that the outer most folder `files` is fixed):

```
{
   "name":"files",
   "type":"folder",
   "path":"files",
   "items":[
      {
         "name":"images",
         "type":"folder",
         "path":"files\/images",
         "items":[
                     "name":"announcement",
                     "type":"folder",
                     "path":"files\/images\/announcement",
                     "items":[]
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"ss",
         "type":"folder",
         "path":"files\/ss",
         "items":[
                     "name":"others",
                     "type":"folder",
                     "path":"files\/ss\/others",
                     "items":[
                                 "name":"sub",
                                 "type":"folder",
                                 "path":"files\/ss\/sub",
                                 "items":[]
                             ]
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"sound",
         "type":"folder",
         "path":"files\/sound",
         "items":[

         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"New folder (4)",
         "type":"folder",
         "path":"files\/New folder (4)",
         "items":[

         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"New folder (5)",
         "type":"folder",
         "path":"files\/New folder (5)",
         "items":[

         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"New folder (6)",
         "type":"folder",
         "path":"files\/New folder (6)",
         "items":[

         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

With some code I was able to split each `$list` strings into multidimensional arrays:

```
function explodeToNestedArray($delimiter, $key, $dir)
    { 
        $value = array();
        $keys = explode($delimiter, $key, 2);

        $value["name"]=$keys[0];
        $value["type"]= "folder";
        $value["path"]= $dir . "/" . $keys[0];
        if ($keys[1] == null) $value["items"] = array();
        else
        $value["items"] = explodeToNestedArray("/", $keys[1], $dir . "/" . $keys[0]);
        return $value;
    }
  $list2 = array();
  foreach ($list as $value) {
    $list2[] = explodeToNestedArray("/", $value, "");
  }
      print_r($list2);
```

The resulting `$list2` looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => images
            [type] => folder
            [path] => /images
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [name] => announcement
                    [type] => folder
                    [path] => /images/announcement
                    [items] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => images
            [type] => folder
            [path] => /images
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [name] => background
                    [type] => folder
                    [path] => /images/background
                    [items] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => images
            [type] => folder
            [path] => /images
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [name] => background
                    [type] => folder
                    [path] => /images/background
                    [items] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => thumbnail
                            [type] => folder
                            [path] => /images/background/thumbnail
                            [items] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => images
            [type] => folder
            [path] => /images
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [name] => character
                    [type] => folder
                    [path] => /images/character
                    [items] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => images
            [type] => folder
            [path] => /images
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [name] => character
                    [type] => folder
                    [path] => /images/character
                    [items] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => frame
                            [type] => folder
                            [path] => /images/character/frame
                            [items] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => images
            [type] => folder
            [path] => /images
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [name] => character
                    [type] => folder
                    [path] => /images/character
                    [items] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => party
                            [type] => folder
                            [path] => /images/character/party
                            [items] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
..........etc*
)
```

How do I merge subarrays ["item"] elements inside `$list2` if they have the same `["name"] = foldername` so I can have desired result?
Using `array_merge_recursive();` ended up separating all the subarrays into different type, name, path and items arrays.

Comment: Are all `type` values `folder` or should the last levels have a different value?

Comment: @Nick there are two available: "folder" and "file". But I limited the use-case to just folder so yes, all the `type` should be fixed as `folder`

Comment: @HuỳnhLong as the 1st step - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/60807e0aba89f77046351f68c7ab81602afa342c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do what you want. It traverses each element of the list, looking for each key in the list element in the output array. If not found, it creates a new entry in the output; if it is found then we continue down the tree to determine where to add the lower parts of the key. Note that for leaf elements we add a `type` of `file`, if you want it to be `folder` just remove the condition on that line (i.e. `$element['type'] = 'folder';`).

```
$output = array('name' => 'files', 'type' => 'folder', 'path' => 'files', 'items' => array());

function explodeToNestedArray($delimiter, $key, &$output) {
    $keys = explode($delimiter, $key, 2);
    if (($k = array_search($keys[0], array_column($output['items'], 'name'))) === false) {
        // need to create an element
        $element = array('name' => $keys[0], 'path' => $output['path'] . "/{$keys[0]}", 'items' => array());
        $element['type'] = (count($keys) == 1) ? 'file' : 'folder';
        if (count($keys) == 2) explodeToNestedArray($delimiter, $keys[1], $element);
        $output['items'][] = $element;
    }
    else {
        // any children to add?
        if (count($keys) == 2) {
            explodeToNestedArray($delimiter, $keys[1], $output['items'][$k]);
            // change the type to folder in case it was previously a leaf
            $output['items'][$k]['type'] = 'folder';
        }
    }
}

foreach ($list as $node) {
    explodeToNestedArray('/', $node, $output);
}
```

Output is too long to show here but you can see it in this [demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/0vjWQ).

Comment: Seems it's Ok +1. But very strange that `background` has type `file` and subdirs at the same time :) Perhaps, it will not be with real data. Else the code should check real leaves to mark as file but not by data from one string

Comment: @splash58 thanks - I hadn't noticed that in the long output. It's because the type of an element wasn't being changed when children were added. I've edited the answer and demo with a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl, let me know in the comments if it works and I'll expand on my answer.

```
function explodeToNestedArray($delimiter, $list, $dir) {

    $data = array();

    foreach($list as $key) {

        $value = array();
        $keys = explode($delimiter, $key, 2);

        $value["name"] = $keys[0];
        $value["type"] = "folder";
        $value["path"] = $dir . "/" . $keys[0];

        $items = array($keys[1]);
        $value["items"] = ($keys[1] == null ? array() : explodeToNestedArray("/", $items, $dir . "/" . $keys[0]));

        if(!isset($data[$keys[0]])) $data[$keys[0]] = array();
        $data[$keys[0]][] = $value;

    }

    return $data;

}

$list = explodeToNestedArray("/", $list, "");

print_r($list);
```

Comment: `foreach($list as $key) ` sorry but $list was undefined inside the function

Comment: IDK why but I got Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: That isn't possible, maybe var_dump $list at the start of the explodeToNestedArray function to see if it is coming through correctly.

Comment: the `$list` is still a normal arrays 
I think the problem is in `explodeToNestedArray("/", $keys[1], $dir . "/" . $keys[0]))`
`$keys[1]` is a string now inside of an array

Comment: You're right. Let me figure out a solution now, will make an edit shortly.

Comment: Only I can' t find merged sub-arrays in output of this code?

Comment: @splash58 What do you mean?

Comment: OP: *How do I merge subarrays ["item"] elements inside $list2 if they have the same ["name"] = foldername*